# Is there a setting to force a hanging indent on bulleted/numbered lists WITHOUT hard wrapping?

Tags: indentation, wrapping

Basically, I'd like to have long entries for bulleted / numbered lists that automatically indent like so:

```
1. Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of 
   religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or 
   abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the 
   right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition 
   the government for a redress of grievances.
```

I'm aware that `formatoptions=n` will do this for numbered lists and `formatoptions=c` will do this for asterisks (provided they are defined as comment leaders with `comments=fb:*`), but this only works by forcing an automatic hard wrap. I'd prefer to avoid this situation, since in order to edit the paragraph, I then have to manually `J`oin the lines back into one, make the edits, and then `gqq` to reformat.

The `breakindent` setting gets me halfway there, with automatic indentation for softwrapped paragraphs, but it only provides indentation identical to the first line. Is there any setting that combines `breakindent`'s softwrap support with `formatoptions+=cn`'s numbered- and bulleted-list recognition?

Comment: Afaik, this is not possible (compare also `:h 'breakindentopt'`). I think you have to create a feature request either on the vim_dev mailing list or on the issue tracker on [github](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues).

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this question in the future: The GitHub feature request is [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1661); if you're a C programmer, we'd sure appreciate your help in building this feature, and if you're just a mere mortal, maybe you can at least chime in and state your support for it? :)

Comment: I’m fairly certain I just edit the paragraph and do `gqap` (or something more fine-grained), no joining first

Answer (score 3):

As of Vim 8.2.0139, there are no configuration options to specify this behaviour. Furthermore, any changes to the behaviour of Vim's soft wrapping via `'wrap'` will require implementing in the source code: there is no workaround possible by using Vimscript.*

See the [feature request that Ryan Lue (who asked this question) added to the Vim project's issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1661) after brief discussion in the comments.

As of January 21st 2020, this issue remains open.

<sub>* Except, I guess, an *extremely* hacky and difficult-to-implement-properly one which worked by actually using hard-wrapping and converting to soft-wrapping on save.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour has been requested somewhat intermittently in various contexts [1], but so far (March 2021; vim 8.2, NeoVim 0.4.4) there doesn't seem to be a reasonable way to achieve this.

**If this feature would benefit you, please upvote/comment** on the [GitHub feature request for vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1661) (still open as of March 2021) and also for the corresponding one for [NeoVim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/10206).

---

I use `showbreak` which is less than satisfactory but still, for me, makes my markdown more readable than nothing. Using:

```
set textwidth=0
set wrap
set linebreak  " wrap line at word boundaries
set breakindent
set showbreak=\ \ " note: \_\_, _ = <white space character>
```

Will produce (line numbers included to reveal the softwraps):

```
  1 * unordered lists
  2 * with a long line will
      break OK.
  3   * ...also when they are
        nested.
  4
  5 Non-lists will get a
      hanging indentation as        
      well though.
  6
  8 1. lists with any bullet
      wider than 1 character        
      won't be perfectly
      aligned.
  9 10. Even more-so when the
      bullet width varies
      within the list.
```

Something similar could probably be achieved using `breakindentopt` with `min` and `shift`.

With hard line breaks there seem to be various ways (e.g. plugin [bullets.vim](https://github.com/dkarter/bullets.vim), see [issue #38](https://github.com/dkarter/bullets.vim/issues/38)). Hard line breaks however is totally against my philosophy when it comes to Markdown and prose/flowing text.

---

**[1]:**

- https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/g1m82w/better_soft_wrap/
- https://github.com/reedes/vim-pencil/issues/60
- https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax/issues/161
- https://github.com/dkarter/bullets.vim/issues/38

Comment: …and the feature has just made its way into both Vim (a month ago) and NeoVim (today)!